# What is the best Way to add flutter path on mac?

Tags: flutter, macos, zsh

How to add Flutter path on mac zsh globally , no need to add it in every window of terminal

Comment: from the same shell copy?

Comment: So what happens when you type `flutter doctor` IN the project? (Seems you've been writing it outside the project...)

Comment: yes, from same shell

Comment: when writing "flutter doctor", an outside project I write this to test whether flutter was found or not.
when  open the terminal and type "flutter" without cd to any folder it works and found flutter, but when cd to any folder does not fount flutter

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps go to your `.zshrc` file and add your path to `flutter/bin`?

My `.zshrc` file is located here:

```
Users/[my_user_name]/.zshrc
```

Usually, you won't be able to see this file using Finder because it's hidden. In your home directory from Finder hit `Cmd + Shift + .` to see hidden files. Then you will be able to access them. If that file doesn't exist, create one.

Once you're in that file, add the path to your `flutter/bin`. In my case, that path looked like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/[my_user_name]/Development/flutter/bin/"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I put this code 

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/[my_user_name]/Development/flutter/bin/" in .bash_profile file and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In the flutter documentation:

> Add the flutter tool to your path:
>
> ```
>  export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
> ```
>
> This command sets your PATH variable for the current terminal window only. To permanently add Flutter to your path, see [Update your path.](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path)

The solution is what Karolina said, you edit the `.zshrc` file to be able to use the flutter command for all terminal sessions.

Answer (score 0):

go to your `.bash_profile` file and add the path to flutter/bin?

For example

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/[my_user_name]/Development/flutter/bin/"
```